# JGroups(JChannel) Chat Application not working on other computer

Tags: java, jgroups

I'm developing a simple chat application using JGroups. The application works perfectly in my computer, but when I try to run it on another computer on the same network, it doesn't work.

```
void start() throws Exception { 
    channel=new JChannel();                
    channel.setReceiver(this);        
    channel.connect("Test");           
}
```

Am I missing any configuration on the start() function? When I run on the other computer, it doesn't recognize the chat instance on the cluster "Test". Maybe it creates another instance of cluster "Test".

Need some help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured IPv6 on the computers? JGoups have sometimes problem to find other instances with IPv6. Try to add the "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" setting to the program startup. What rendezvous module and protocol are you using?

Comment: I'm using the default (guess it's UDP). I'll try to use the preferIPv4Stack=true. Thanks for your time! I'll tell if it worked.

Comment: Didn't work. I'm trying to set the bind_addr now.

Answer (score 2):

What's the output the program shows? If it includes an address of 127.0.0.1, then the nodes won't find each other. In this case, set bind_addr, either `-Djgroups.bind_addr=x.x.x.x`, or `channel.getProtocolStack.findProtocol(TP.class).setValue"bind_addr", "x.x.x.x")`. The latter needs to be done before connecting the channel.
Might also be an IPv6 issue, as mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, the program opens a simple chat window, using swing components. When I run two or more programs in my computer it send messages to the others perfectly, but when I run in another computer, it doesn't seem to "recognize" the chat windows opened in my computer. I'll try to set the bind_addr. It's like channel.getProtocolStack.findProtocol(TP.class).setValue"bind_addr", "192.168.10.101")? 192.168.10.101 is my network addres.

Comment: I'm getting  " Can not set java.net.InetAddress field org.jgroups.protocols.TP.bind_addr to java.lang.String
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source) ". When trying to set bind_addr. I'm trying channel.getProtocolStack().findProtocol(TP.class).setValue("bind_addr", new String("192.168.10.101"));

Comment: Edit: Problem solved. channel.getProtocolStack().findProtocol(TP.class).setValue("bind_addr",InetAddress.getByName("192.168.10.101") );